# How to get the port number in node.js when a request is processed?

Tags: node.js

If I have two node.js servers running, how can I tell which server called the processRequest function?

```
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
function processRequest(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("hello world, I'm on port: " + ???.port + "\n");
}
var server1 = http.createServer(processRequest).listen(80);
var server2 = https.createServer(processRequest).listen(443);
```

Originally I wanted the port number, but couldn't find the object/variable to give it to me.  Based on the below answer it makes more sense to determine encrypted vs non-encrypted since the point is to know which of the http servers the request came in on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of checking port numbers, you can also check the server instance or the connection object:

```
var http = require('http'),
    https = require('https');
function processRequest(req, res) {
  var isSSL = (req.socket.encrypted ? true : false);
  // alternate method:
  // var isSSL = (this instanceof https.Server);
  // or if you want to check against a specific server instance:
  // var isServer1 = (this === server1);

  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('hello world, i am' + (!isSSL ? ' not' : '') + ' encrypted!\n');
}
var server1 = http.createServer(processRequest).listen(80);
var server2 = https.createServer(processRequest).listen(443);
```

Comment: But Chris asked how to determine port number, not what service is running or what protocol is being used.

Comment: @jww true, but this is a better solution to my situation, which is why I accepted it. Port numbers can change, but encrypted vs not encrypted will always be the better test in this case.  I should have worded the question better.

Answer (score 21):

The `req` parameter is an instance of [IncomingMessage](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_http_incomingmessage) from which you can access the [socket](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_message_socket).

From there you can access both the localPort and remotePort.

Something like:

```
console.log(req.socket.localPort);
console.log(req.socket.remotePort);
```

Comment: Unfortunately `localPort` doesn't work for secure connection. It is `undefined`. For those who seek solution, you can use in combination with stratovarious's answer. `req.socket.address()` and `req.socket.remoteAddress()` worked for me

Answer (score 8):

In case you are using **`http://localhost:<port_number>`**, then you can get the port number using ***`req.headers.host`*** property.

*Example:*

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.headers.host); // localhost:8080
    console.log(req.headers.host.split(':')[1]); // 8080
})
server.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 6):

This way you get the port number:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer().listen(8080);

server.on('request', function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html; charset: UTF-8"});
    res.write("Hello from Node! ");
    res.write(" Server listening on port " + this.address().port);
    res.end();
});
```